# Set default value in the searchable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want to set `Egypt` as the default value in the searchable dropdown menu . Currently there is no value set. This is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35nk2cwo/1/) link

I tried to set like this, it sets the default value to `Egypt` but when I opened the list then `Egypt` is not highlighted in the list

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-countires").val("Egypt");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value field to the input element.

Check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38kapd0r/).

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search countries" id="search-countires" onkeyup="filterFunction(this,event)" value="Egypt">
```

Comment: It didn't work. When I opened the list, Egypt is not highlighted

Answer (score 0):

add .change()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-countires").val("Egypt").change();
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. When I opened the list, Egypt is not highlighted